# JavaScript for opening images in a new tab

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question regarding html and js.
I want to make all pictures in `<img>` tags openable in a new tab without setting up manually a href link for every image. My problem is that I have over 17.000 Pictures on my website and it would be very laborious to do this for every single image. So basically every src link should be set to the href link for the `<img>` tag.

Is there any possibility to realize that ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That sounds like an awful UX. Why not just implement a simple lightbox viewer?

Comment: But the answer is "sure". A simple script will accomplish that. What have you tried? See [ask], then revise to show us your page structure, at least.

Comment: It's especially awful since you're apparently throwing huge quantities of full-size images at your visitors. Load time must be atrocious.

Comment: The site mostly contains historic pictures. The origin of the site started in 2006. Since then the sites html files were modernized for current technologies, but stayed in his original concept. One goal of our site is to make the websites data saveable for everyone, since it is a huge tool for archives. Because of that we want to keep it working just with the minimum needed additional files. The original author also experienced a crash of an old website builder which resulted in a big loss.

Comment: And we also are no experts in developing, so we can't developers something own, which would be easy to save and reuse in many years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, haven't tested it (im on mobile) but something like this:

```
const gallery = document.querySelectorAll(img) 
gallery.forEach(image => {
   let src = image.getAttribute('src')
   image.addEventListener('click', function () {
       window.open(src)
   }
}
```

Once it's done add img { cursor: pointer } to your css to tell users they can click on it

You'd be better of with a script changing your images to links, and don't forget lazy load

Comment: Thank you very much. I fixed it to the following and it worked:

const gallery = document.querySelectorAll("img") 
gallery.forEach(image => {
   let src = image.getAttribute('src')
   image.addEventListener('click', function () {
       window.open(src)
   }
)})